# StyleSheet.create "not covered by flow"

Tags: css, react-native, flowtype

I am using flow 0.42.0 in a react native project with nuclide.

With the default project, I get the following message:

[image]

Along with the following errors:

```
> flow check
index.ios.js:40
 40:             <View style={style.container}>
                                    ^^^^^^^^^ property `container`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value
 40:             <View style={style.container}>
                              ^^^^^ undefined

index.ios.js:40
 40:             <View style={style.container}>
                                    ^^^^^^^^^ property `container`. Property not found in
 40:             <View style={style.container}>
                              ^^^^^ Array

index.ios.js:41
 41:                 <Text style={style.welcome}>
                                        ^^^^^^^ property `welcome`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value
 41:                 <Text style={style.welcome}>
                                  ^^^^^ undefined

index.ios.js:41
 41:                 <Text style={style.welcome}>
                                        ^^^^^^^ property `welcome`. Property not found in
 41:                 <Text style={style.welcome}>
                                  ^^^^^ Array

index.ios.js:44
 44:                 <Text style={style.instructions}>
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `instructions`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value
 44:                 <Text style={style.instructions}>
                                  ^^^^^ undefined

index.ios.js:44
 44:                 <Text style={style.instructions}>
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `instructions`. Property not found in
 44:                 <Text style={style.instructions}>
                                  ^^^^^ Array

index.ios.js:47
 47:                 <Text style={style.instructions}>
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `instructions`. Property cannot be accessed on possibly undefined value
 47:                 <Text style={style.instructions}>
                                  ^^^^^ undefined

index.ios.js:47
 47:                 <Text style={style.instructions}>
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `instructions`. Property not found in
 47:                 <Text style={style.instructions}>
                                  ^^^^^ Array


Found 8 errors
```

This issue ( https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/issues/631 ) seemed to suggest that the correct type was `StyleSheet.Styles`, but that gives me the same message (and the same errors from above):

[image]

Is there any way I can get proper flow typing working here?

For reference, the complete file is:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 * @flow
 */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

export default class PartalkReact extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text style={styles.welcome}>
                    Welcome to React Native!
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                    To get started, edit index.ios.js
                </Text>
                <Text style={styles.instructions}>
                    Press Cmd+R to reload,{'\n'}
                    Cmd+D or shake for dev menu
                </Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('PartalkReact', () => PartalkReact);
```

**Edit** After upgrading to flow 0.45.0, as per the comments, I no longer have problems in my files, but react itself fails with the following errors: https://pastebin.com/raw/Ngpagayi

Answer (score 4):

The warning is because of the third party has not integrated flow to their end. In our case, the StyleSheet is giving the warning so react native is the third party who has not integrated flow. React native only included flow in some components only may be core ones and it was officially declared by them.

As told by you that react-native is using flow in stylesheet so i came to a conclusion:

```
import type { StyleObj } from 'react-
native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheetTypes';

type Props = {
    style?: StyleObj,
};
```

The other way is to upgrade the flow.

Cheers :)

Comment: But the react native source has flow typing on the `create` function. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet.js

Comment: Also, it seems that I can't cmd+click on the create function to jump to it, which suggests that flow isn't parsing the react native source for some reason.

Comment: I apologize; I'm still very new to react. How exactly do I use the excerpt you provided? Just adding it within the file yields no difference. Could you modify my example file as a demonstration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143620/discussion-between-daniel-centore-and-codesingh).

Comment: Just to summarize the chat: @Codesingh said that the code works fine in flow.org and I responded that it doesn't for me ( see http://i.stack.imgur.com/rNs5f.jpg )

Comment: Friend not mine, your code that is in question.. The fact is that you are using older version of flow.

Comment: When upgrading to 0.45.0, my code works fine but react fails now ( https://pastebin.com/dErUikyk ). Perhaps my `.flowconfig` ( https://pastebin.com/k6g85S9s ) needs a change? I am using React 0.44.0.

Comment: Do you have this code working in a real setup? If so, could you pass along your `.flowconfig` and `.package.json`? I still can't get this working for the life of me.

Comment: The problem still exists with recent versions of flow (I'm on 0.134.0 and stylesheet content are still not covered by flow).

Answer (score 1):

I've been using the following to pretty good success
This will show errors if you use non existent style properties and enable code completion

```
const rawStyles = { ... }
export const styles: typeof rawStyles = StyleSheet.create(rawStyles)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still encountering this in late 2018, the preferred solution changed to:

```
import type {
  ViewStyleProp,
  TextStyleProp,
  ImageStyleProp,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/StyleSheet/StyleSheet';
```

Source: https://github.com/flow-typed/flow-typed/issues/631

Answer (score 0):

Add this above your class:

```
type Props = {
    style?: StyleSheet.Styles;
};
```